# iPhone4 iOS5 how to save MPMediaItem with Core Data?

Tags: core-data, ios5, iphone-4, persistent-storage, mpmediaitem

I'm trying to save a list of music files that the user has selected from the iPod music library. To do so, I get a list of **persistentIDs** which I will use to query the library later. I do this as follows:

```
NSNumber* persistentID = [mediaItem valueForProperty:[MPMediaItem persistentIDPropertyForGroupingType: MPMediaGroupingTitle]];
```

This method returns an id, which I assign to NSNumber. The numbers that I get are of this form: 4158583232547482294 . **Which number format** should I select to store such numbers in core data. Is this a Integer64?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mind sharing a bit more on how you stored the music files that the user selected? I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: How to do you use NSNumber to get the MPMediaItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the Wikipedia, I can confirm that the 19 digit unsigned integer is indeed **integer64**. Here are other integer sizes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Common_integral_data_types

Comment: @jeicam From documentation "Value is an NSNumber object representing an NSUInteger data type."